# How to validate user inputs using regexp

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to validate the  user input using regular expression. It should be a number with 6 or 7 digit (between 0-9), no trailing and leading spaces should be allowed. Currently i am using `^\d{6,7}` the problem here is even if i type 6 or 7 digits am getting the error message.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What programming language and which regex dialect?

Comment: [working fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/cBqtq/) (it uses javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regex would be `^\d{6,7}$` or the user would be able to put more than 7 digits.
You are doing a bad coding, because even your regex should match 6-7 digits.

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com?30r0u)

Answer (score 0):

use this to allow only number

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="txtmobile" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Numbers Only" 
                                                ValidationExpression="[0-9]*" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: asp? and what about the 6-7 digits thing?